# Prove that an open interval (0,1) and a closed interval [0,1] are not homeomorphic.

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology

Prove that an open interval (0.1) and a closed interval [0,1] are not homeomorphic.

I am trying to prove this statement but only vague ideas on how to start.

Not using connectedness properties.

Please help

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42308/continuous-bijection-from-0-1-to-0-1). Its really interesting!

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $f:[0,1]\to(0,1)$ is a homeomorphism. In particular, then, it is a continuous surjection. Since $f$ is a continuous real-valued function on the closed interval $[0,1],$ it has an absolute minimum value, call it $m$. Then $m\in(0,1),$ and $\frac m2\in(0,1).$ Since $f$ is surjective, there is some $x\in[0,1]$ such that $f(x)=\frac m2\lt m.$ This contradicts the fact that $m$ is the minimum value of $f.$

Comment: Please correct the closed interval in your map

Comment: @dmtri Oops. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the sequence $\left(\frac1n\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ in $(0,1)$. It has no subsequence which converges to an element of $(0,1)$. However, every sequence of elements of $[0,1]$ has a subsequence that converges to an element of $[0,1]$, by the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem and because $[0,1]$ is closed. Therefore, $(0,1)$ and $[0,1]$ are not homeomorphic.

Answer (score 3):

The open interval is not compact metric space,  but the closed is.

Comment: Thanks but it is not enough please show it

Comment: The continuous image of compact like the closed interval is compact... And the open interval is not compcat

Answer (score 1):

Removing an endpoint (i.e. $0$ or $1$) from the closed interval $\left[ 0,1\right]$ leaves either $\left( 0,1\right]$ or $\left[ 0,1\right)$, both of which are connected spaces. On the other hand, removing *any* point from $(0,1)$ will leave a disconnected space (with two components). See the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1541868/homeomorphism-between-two-intervals-in-mathbb-r).

This formalizes the feeling that $0$ and $1$ are "special points" in the space $\left[0,1\right]$. This kind of argument is often useful when dealing with simple spaces. For another example, see my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3080920/are-the-letters-o-and-infty-homeomorphic).